# Jogo da memória com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou desenvolvendo esse jogo para um aplicativo mobile, juntamente do ionic, angular2, CLI, entre outros. Porém á lógica é totalmente com javascript mas como todo jogo tem suas regras eu travei na parte em que o jogador não pode "virar" mais de duas cartas e verificar se as duas cartas que foram viradas são iguais, se forem iguais elas permanecem viradas e se não forem são viradas para baixo ao mesmo tempo.

Para o jogador poder virar as cartas eu troquei o z-index por script ao clicar. As imagens que começam aparecendo estão com o z-index = 999, já as imagens das cartas viradas começam com o z-index = 998, quando as imagens com o z-index = 999 é clicada eu passei uma função que troca o z-index dela para 997 fazendo com que as imagens das cartas "viradas" apareçam como no código abaixo:

```js
// Array com todas as imagens possiveis
var imagensArray=[
 'assets/img/1.jpg',
 'assets/img/2.jpg',
 'assets/img/3.jpg',
 'assets/img/4.jpg',
 'assets/img/5.jpg',
 'assets/img/6.jpg',
 'assets/img/7.jpg',
 'assets/img/8.jpg',
 'assets/img/9.jpg',
 'assets/img/10.jpg'
];
// Função que cria as cartas da fase 1

 function criaTabuleiro1(){

 var qtdCartas = 4;

  for(var i=1; i<=qtdCartas; i++){
   var cartas = document.createElement("img");
   cartas.src = "assets/img/carta.jpg";
  cartas.style.marginRight = "10px";
  cartas.style.position = "relative";
  cartas.style.zIndex = "999";
  cartas.id = "c" + i;
  document.getElementById("cartas").appendChild(cartas);

    // função anonima onlick que recebe outra função criada mais abaixo
  cartas.onclick = function(){
   viraCarta(this);
  }
  
 }
 
 // Gera as imagens dar cartas "viradas" aparti do array selecionado
 for(i = 0; i < selecionado.length; i++){
  
   var cartasViradas = document.createElement("img");
   cartasViradas.src = selecionado[i];
   cartasViradas.style.marginRight = "10px";
   cartasViradas.style.position = "relative";
   cartasViradas.style.zIndex = "998";
   cartasViradas.id = "virada" + i;
   document.getElementById("cartasViradas").appendChild(cartasViradas);
  
   
  } 
}
// Armazena aleatoriamente 4 cartas das 10 possiveis do array imagensArray
var selecionado = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // Escolha aleatoriamente um da matriz de faces
    var randomInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagensArray.length);
 var face = imagensArray[randomInd];
 
 selecionado.push(face);
 selecionado.push(face);
 
    imagensArray.splice(randomInd, 1);
}

selecionado.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});


    

var qtdCartasViradas = 0;

function viraCarta(e){
 var cartaId = e.id;
 
 //Remove do balão clicado a função estourar()
 document.getElementById(cartaId).setAttribute("onclick","");
 document.getElementById(cartaId).style.zIndex = "997";

 qtdCartasViradas += 1;
 
}
```

```css
.cartas{
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .cartasViradas{
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Jogo memoria</title>
</head>

<body onload="criaTabuleiro1()">
<div id="cartas" class="cartas">
    <div class="cartasViradas" id="cartasViradas"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa lógica pois já tentei e não consigo saber através do código em qual carta o jogador está clicando.

Comment: Eu tratei uma questão semelhante à essa de detectar clique em posição num Resta Um que fiz em JS; no caso, eu usava de fato `<table>` pois fazia sentido. Se quiser dar uma pesquisada: https://github.com/jeffque/peg-kitten-solitaire; se conseguir fazer uma resposta adequada após a leitura do código nesse repositório, responda sua pergunta com dignidade que eu votarei a favor de sua própria resposta